# Compiling SQLite with Visual Studio C++ 2013 Throws error for .c file

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I have added sqlite3.c file into my project.
And #include. Here is the code:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

I compile the program and it throws the following error:

```
1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3080702\sqlite3.c(15705): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
1>          Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3080702\sqlite3.c(19741): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'sqlite3_mutex *'
1>          Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3080702\sqlite3.c(20665): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
1>          Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3080702\sqlite3.c(20677): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
1>          Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3080702\sqlite3.c(21142): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
1>          Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3080702\sqlite3.c(21256): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
1>          Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3080702\sqlite3.c(21411): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
```

But there is no error that a header or file is not found. Everything is found and the errors are just outputted above

Comment: Sounds like you're compiling C code as C++ code. Don't do that.

Comment: Sorry I did exactly the same:  your code + sqllite.c, with MSVC2013 everything compiles fine.  Which compiler do you use ?  which compiling options ?

Comment: @CaptainOblious If I compile it as C, then the following error will be thrown:

`1>cl : Command line error D8045: cannot compile C file '..\..\..\..\..\..\..\libraries\sqlite-amalgamation-3080702\sqlite-amalgamation-3080702\sqlite3.c' with the /clr option`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the solution. I compiled the C code as C++, but changing it was not enough.

I write it for future visitors:

First, I had to change file's (ONLY FILE) property. Right-click on the file and select properties, under the `C/C++`, select `Advanced` and then select `Compile As` and set it to `C` (neither default nor `C++`).

Then, you should make sure that your .c file is compiled without clr. Well, to do that, under the same `C/C++` set of menu, select `"Common Langugae Runtime Support"` and set it to `No Support....`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 17 and I would add to this, find the settings for "Precompiled Header" and set that to "Not Using Precompiled Headers".